# How to update a UILabel class from another class

Tags: swift

After looking at various answers to this question, I haven't found once that fits the exact scenario I am in.

Quite simply, I create a UILabelClass as such:

```
class pointsLabel: UILabel {

override func willMove(toSuperview newSuperview: UIView?) {
    text = points
   // Somehow watch UpdateChecker and update text when change
}

}
```

And have a UpdateChecker NSObject that is told to run when the app launches:

```
class UpdateChecker: NSObject {

func watchForUpdates () {
 receivesUpdateFromServer {
points = pointUpdateFromServer
}
}

}
```

The pointsLabel class is assigned to various UILabels in interface builder on different view controllers.

How can I best and most efficiently get the pointsLabel to update it's text when the UpdateChecker receives an update? If I use the NSNotification method the problem is that every time a View loads with the label, another notification observer gets registered, and doesn't get removed when the label disappears.

Comment: You can use delegation to do this in better way.

Comment: Embedded this label inside inner view, use delegation just create a protocol and pass it by value to the parent viewcontroller. Use method Prepare for Segue to configure it.

Comment: You’ve included a little more code here, which is a good first step. Thanks. But you’re saying that the problem is that if you add an observer, it’s never getting removed. I would have thought that you’d want to show us where (a) you’re posting your notification; (b) where you’re adding your observer for that notification; and (c) where you’re removing your observer.

Comment: Well, I added your code exactly as you've written it in your answer to the UILabel class and it doesn't get removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said:

> The `UILabel` can be displayed in different view controllers, so I can't tell it to register a `NSNotification` observer on load because that means every time the label is loaded it registers the observer again.

No, this is precisely what you should do for capturing updates to some `Int` value that needs to be reflected in multiple view controllers. Sure, every time a view controller is loaded (e.g. `viewDidLoad`) you’d add the `NotificationCenter` observer, and then remove the observer in `deinit`. But adding/removing observers is not an appreciably expensive process, so just do it. It sounds like the logical solution for the problem you describe.

FWIW, this does *not* seem like a good delegate-protocol candidate if multiple view controllers need to be informed of changes to this object. The delegate-protocol pattern is best used when there is a one-to-one relationship between an object and its delegate. But when you have many different view controllers that would like to be the “delegate”, in turn, then an observer pattern makes a lot more sense.

---

By the way, you reference something that “constantly receives updates” in conjunction with it being a “user default”. If there’s anything in your question that I’d take a hard look at, it would be the notion of using user defaults to capture something that isn’t really a default, but rather something that is presumably a model object that is frequently changing.

---

For example, let’s assume that I had defined some custom notification:

```
extension Notification.Name {
    static let didUpdateFoo = Notification.Name(Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier! + ".didUpdateFoo")
}
```

And when `Foo` is updated, you’d do:

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .didUpdateFoo, object: foo)
```

Then a view controller that wants to observe this notification would:

```
private var didReceiveFooObserver: NSObjectProtocol?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    didReceiveFooObserver = NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .didUpdateFoo, object: nil, queue: .main) { [weak self] notification in
        guard let foo = notification.object as? Int else { return }
        self?.fooLabel.text = "\(foo)"
    }
}

deinit {
    if let token = didReceiveFooObserver {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(token)
    }
}
```

Comment: How do I use deinit? I tried simply deinit { ... } but that does nothing when the view containing the label disappears?

Comment: First, is `deinit` actually being called? For example, if you add an observer with the block-based rendition of the API and neglected to use `[weak self]` reference, your observer might be keeping a strong reference, preventing `deinit` from getting called at all. No point in going further until you make sure that `deinit` is getting called. But see answer for example if you were using notification center.

Comment: Well I don't actually set it up anywhere. It's a UILabel swift class that I assign to a UILabel in a view controller on the storyboard. I don't create the label any where else.

Comment: I've also applied your example to the UILabel class and it does not perform the desired result, the notification still gets registered twice and isn't removed when the label disappears.

Comment: I’d suggest you edit your question to show us precisely what you’re doing. It’s impossible to diagnose on the basis of the information provided thus far. But, again, as I asked above, is `deinit` getting called? If not, you have to solve that problem first. No point in wondering about delegates or observers or anything else, until you confirm whether `deinit` is getting called. And, when you fix that, if you still have questions, edit your question to include [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I have updated the post to more precisely show what the situation is. Also I have tried adding deinit but it doesn't get called when the label dissapears. I'm likely not doing it right, I haven't had much experience with deinit.

Comment: Deinit was not being called due to the container UIViewController having a loop that didn't stop when dismissed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use property observers for the same.
Make a computed property like below:

```
var updatedValue = 0 {
    didSet {
        scoreLabel.text = "Score: \(score)"
    }
}
```

scoreLabel is your label which automatically updates when score receives any changes. You don't need to go with NSNotification observers.
You can access score property from class which receives updates.
You can go through this link to get more clear understanding for property observers
https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/property-observers-in-swift/

Comment: Hi, could you show a bit more detail on the usage of this?

Comment: You can go through this link, it gives a very clear implementation and how to use it: https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/property-observers-in-swift/

Comment: This looks promising, but im not sure how to write it so that the label observes the external score/points Int and updates when it changes?

Comment: Is this only for local classes?